# Create a list with numpy arrays from a list that contains the directories of images in Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

I have a list named `dir`with the directories of 18900 RGB images (3 channels) with dimensions 64x64 pixels in my drive in Google Colab. I opened the first image with  the Image module from PIL library: `img = Image.open(dir[0])`. I converted the image to an array with numpy library: `array = np.asarray(img)`. Now, i want to make a list with arrays that represent my images. So, i made the following script with a loop in order to open all the images:

```
img = [None]* len(dir)

for i in range(len(dir)):
  img[i] = Image.open(dir[i])
```

but it keeps running for about 20 minutes and i do not have a result.
Is there a fastest way to create a list with 18900 arrays from the list with the 18900 directories of my images?

Comment: Google Colab is particularly long when it comes to loading images from Drive, so even if your images are really small (like 256x256 pixels), it's normal for Colab to take so much time. I'm afraid there's no perfect answer as long as you stay with Drive, but I've heard of other solutions (such as GCP) that might improve the global running time.

Comment: My images are RGB (3 channels) with dimensions of 64x64 pixels.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem : even if your images are light, Colab will still take an absurdly high amount of time to load them, compare to what you can achieve on your local computer

Comment: Don't know about Colab , but multithreading is often used in such cases, eg. `with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=32) as executor: executor.map(read_image, range(len(dir)))` with `def read_image(i): img[i] = numpy.asarray(Image.open(dir[i]))`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is IO-bound. This is lingo for: while your code is running, it spends the majority of its time waiting for your hard-drive to send data. Unfortunately, there is no one magic line that you can write that makes your IO  run fast. However, there are a two things that you can change to minimize the pain in (loose) order of increasing complexity.

1. Change your file format to a format that supports multiple images (e.g. tiff) or use a binary format directly (npz, h5). Opening a new file is **much** much more expensive than reusing an already opened file.
2. Compress your data on disk. It will take time to inflate the data after you have read it, but depending on how bad the connection to your storage is, it can be much faster.
3. Change your storage's filesystem (reformat). This won't be possible in collab, but I add it here for completeness anyway.
4. Upgrade to a paid instance with a better filesystem.

---

Among all these options, I would go with the first and second. I would download all the data to your local computer and, assuming all the data fits into memory, I would create a single, compressed, npz file (or h5) that contains all the images stored along a new batch dimension. I'd upload that one to collab and see if that doesn't reduce loading times to acceptable levels.